# How to check a Stringlist Index?

Tags: delphi, tstringlist

I wanna show 2 different results in delphi with my stringlist.

If the index is smaller than 1 it should show an other result.

I always get a `List index exceeds the maximum error`

Heres my Code.

```
function TForm1.readTable: String;
var
  ini: TIniFile;
  einträge: TStringList;
begin
  try
  einträge := TStringList.Create;
  inipfad := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + '/initest/' + 'config.INI';
  ini := TIniFile.Create(inipfad);
  ini.ReadSections(einträge);
  ShowMessage('geht');

  if einträge.IndexOf < 1 then
    Result := einträge[0]
  else
    Result := einträge[1];

  finally
    ini.Free;
    Einträge.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Changed now to

```
  if einträge.Count <= 0 then begin
    Result := einträge[0]
  end
  else
    Result := einträge[1];
```

And its working without the error. Is this a real solution?

Comment: TStringLIst.IndexOf takes a string parameter which is missing in your code.

Comment: I changed it to   if einträge.Count <= 0 then begin
    Result := einträge[0]
  end
  else
    Result := einträge[1];

Comment: No, if count is 0 then you have nothing in the list, and eintrage[0] doesn't exist. Lists are zero-based, so if count is 1 then the only item in the list that exists is at index 0.

Comment: Ah okay thanks.i wil ltry the new solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `eintrage.indexof<1` you need `eintrage.count=1`.

You should also check that `eintrage.count` is either 1 or 2 in case your list is empty after `ini.ReadSections`.